# What does this circuit do? Reed switch debounce?

Tags: reverse-engineering, reed-switch

I'm trying to reverse engineer a pcb and I'm stuck on this circuit. I believe the capacitors maybe for debounce. The switch is a reed switch. Can anyone shed any light on it?

[image: Circuit diagram]

Comment: is the micro pin configured as an input within a passive pullup enabled?

Comment: Yes I think it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct it is a low pass filter for debouncing the reed switch. Reed switches dont just bounce they can vibrate for some time due to the physical configuration of the contact arms.

[image]

Comment: This is just to block RF noise. True debounce is done internally as simple digital filters.

Comment: I understand the use of the caps but why the resistors? Sorry if this seem a dumb question just trying to learn. :)

Comment: This is a RC (resistor capacitor) filter the time constant is R x C.You need resistance to provide some delay so the capacitor charges less rapidly.